# remove or make transparent background and header colour of table

Tags: html, css, html-table, background

I am trying to remove the white background of a table. I have tried using `background-color: transparent` but this has no effect (changing that colour has no effect also). I am unsure why this is.

The HTML:

```
<form>

        <table class="box-element" th:if="${ not#lists.isEmpty(kitchenRecipes)}">
            <div class="header">Available meals</div>
            <tr>
                <th style="padding-left: 50px">Image</th>
                <th>Meal</th>
                <th>Calories</th>
                <th>Order</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="kitchenRecipe : ${kitchenRecipes}">
                <td style="float: left!important; margin-left: 10px!important;"><img class="row-image" src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/b/64-643199_simple-food-coming-soon-food-clipart.png"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;"><a th:text="${kitchenRecipe.recipeDto.title}"></a></td>
                <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;"><a th:text="${kitchenRecipe.recipeDto.calories}"></a>Calories</td>
                <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;"><a th:href="@{/order/{kitchenId}/{recipeId}(kitchenId=${kitchenRecipe.kitchenDto.id},recipeId=${kitchenRecipe.recipeDto.id})}">View</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

The CSS:

```
.box-element{
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
   background: #ff416c;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ff4b2b, #ff416c);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4b2b, #ff416c);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 0 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   padding: 1rem;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
   width: 80%
}
```

The background appears like this:

[image: Table with white background]

Any help would be appreciatedd

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct, either it's coming from cache of your browser or from any marketing tool which you are using, check the class written 'kitchenRecipes' too,  recheck them, can test via

```
<tr style="background:#ccc;">
```

check and see if it's reflecting grey color in table row.

Answer (score 0):

That reddish color is set in the header class, but I can't see that you have given enough CSS to show why the whole table (more or less) has that background color.

Anyway, notice that the header color although set as a color initially, is then set as a linear-gradient. Elements can have both - with the background-color showing through any transparent parts of the background-image(s).

```
background: #ff416c;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ff4b2b, #ff416c);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4b2b, #ff416c);
```

Look through all the CSS and check for any linear gradients like this and comment them out if they look as though they are this reddish color. This should help you track down what is coloring those cells.

Better yet would be to go to your browser's dev tools and inspect a cell and look to see what is setting the background reddish.